# Showing a demo of my CSS on any website

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have developed a small component which can be put in to any website. Now, I want to develop a code that could demonstrate how would my component look like on any website.

So, the person would come to my page and put in his URL and then my code should embed my custom JS/CSS in to the downloaded HTML and display it. [Something like this](http://demo.webengage.com/awesome-demo/view?url=Google.com&back=http://webengage.com/).

Here, like the feedback tab, I want to show my component any where on that page.

Comment: May I plese know what technologies are you using on server side? Easiest solution will be to load page html and stream out that html with yor css

Comment: This might turn into a mess since their HTML is now loading from your domain, messing up any relative URLs.

Comment: @EmmanuelN ASP.NET on the server. How do I download the HTML?

Comment: If you have asp.net on server side you cane use [Agility Pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/) to load html

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In the example you linked, they are requesting the page specified in the `url` querystring parameter on the server, and then doing more or less the following steps:

1. In the `<head>` tag they are adding a `<base href="url" />` tag to the document.  The `base` tag will make any relative links in the document treat the value in the `href` attribute as their root.  This is how they are getting around broken css / images. (The `base` tag is supported by all browsers)
2. At the end of the document (IE the `</body>` tag) they are injecting the javascript that runs their demos.
3. They serve the modified HTML requested to the browser.

All of this is pretty straight forward in implementation.  You could use regular expressions to match the `<head>` and `</body>` tags for steps 1 and 2 respectively.  Depending on the server platform how you actually request the page will vary, but here are some links to get you started:

- C# - [`HttpWebRequest` object documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.aspx)
- PHP - [HttpRequest::send](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.httprequest-send.php)

Answer (score 15):

Try a [bookmarklet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bookmarklet).

Create a piece of javascript that adds your code into the page such as the following:

```
javascript:(function(){var%20script=document.createElement('script');script.src='http://www.example.org/js/example.js';document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script);})()
```

Add it as the **href** of a link like so:

```
<a href="javascript:(function(){var%20script=document.createElement('script');script.src='http://www.example.org/js/example.js';document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script);})()">Link Text Here</a>
```

Tell your users to drag the link to their bookmark toolbar and click on it on different websites to try your code out.

Some examples: http://www.reclaimprivacy.org/, http://www.readability.com/bookmarklets

Comment: Not many have Bookmark toolbar enabled/visible on their browsers and I think this would confuse my users a bit. Can I anyhow download HTML of the website? I tried $.ajax JQUERY function but it is working on in Safari and not in Chrome, Firefox.

Comment: Downloading an entire site/page is possible but not very practical. You would have to deal with relative/absolute links to content and either mirroring the content or rewriting the link to it to point to the real source (and hotlinking might not be allowed...) as well as the nuances of dynamic content.

Comment: If you are sure you want to go down that route you could try modifying a web-based proxy script to insert your javascript on every page. That would be the easiest route. Something like [cgi-proxy](http://www.jmarshall.com/tools/cgiproxy/) maybe?

Comment: Wow that's the first time I've ever heard of bookmarklets. Completely blew my mind.

Comment: +1 Good answer, I think tell the user to "Bookmark this link" makes fewer assumptions about the browser being used. @Joy I can't imagine someone knowing what CSS is and being unaware of how to add a bookmark.

Comment: @Josh Well, my consideration was that many people have the bookmark tab in the browser disabled. And I know how to add a bookmark

Answer (score 9):

Nathan's answer is the closest to how we have done the [demo feature at WebEngage](http://demo.webengage.com/). To make such a demo functional, you'll need to create a Javascript widget that can be embedded on third party sites. syserr0r's answer on creating a bookmarklet is the simplest approach to do so. Our's is a JAVA backend and we use [HttpClient](http://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/) to fetch the responses. As Nathan suggested, we parse the response, sanitize it and add our widget Javascript to the response. The widget JS code takes it on from there to render the Feedback tab and load a demo short survey.

Disclosure: I am a co-founder and ceo at WebEngage.

Comment: Great to see the WebEngage guys responding here. Thanks for your honesty and insights!

Comment: The pleasure is all Mine Greg. BTW, we just did a tell-all on our engineering blog - http://engineering.webengage.com/2011/11/24/try-a-demo-feature-why-and-how-we-did-it/

Answer (score 2):

You can not do this with JQuery due to cross site scripting restrictions.

I suggest you write a PHP script that downloads the URL specified by the user and includes your widget code and then echo it back to the user.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend using bookmarklets. I've made a bookmarklet generator for adding jQuery-enabled bookmarklets to a page to make development easier.

There's a caliper bookmarklet on the page that you can mess around with just to show an example of it working.

Full disclosure, this is something I've made, I'm not trying to be spammy as I think it's relevant: [zbooks](http://zbooks.zzzzbov.com/)

Answer (score 0):

You could make an iframe page, which loads their page in the iframe, and uses javascript to inject your code into the iframe.

Comment: i tried something like this a while ago, and i think it is not possible because the browser will not allow you to get inside the iframe

Answer (score 0):

Here is my approach...

http://jsfiddle.net/L2kEf/

**html**

```
<iframe src="http://www.bing.com"></iframe>
<div>I am div</div>
```

**css**

```
div { background: red; position: absolute; top: 20px; width: 100px; left:20px;}
iframe{width: 100%; height: 500px;}
```

you can add javascript/jquery too, so you could do something like,

**jQuery** //not 100% sure it would work coz of cross browser thingy, but you know, worth a try.

```
$('div').click(function (){
    $('iframe').contents().html('changed');///
});
```

if this can't change any of the contents, you can display a dialog, to say it would normally work if it was in your website, then use @syserr0r approach for bookmarked users, for better results, since you are offering this kinda services, to developers, im sure they would know about bookmarking, my approach would be rarely used :) so hope it helps.

Comment: yeah.... this won't work unless you change settings of the browser, eg. in FF about:config

Comment: Also, sites like google.com /facebook.com are not displayed in any browser using iFrame.

Comment: @joy I did say he should use the `syserr0r` approach, and do you think , facebook and google would wish to go and use his services? also this was an alternative answer for those who don't know about bookmarking

Answer (score 0):

I had a problem of a similiar nature, and the main obstacle is the cross-domain policy.

You have to ask the user to put your code in a `<script src="...">` or create a proxy solution that would add your code for them.

I went for the proxy and here are my observations:

- it's easy to create a basic proxy in php - there are some php proxies on sourceforge and Ben Alman has created a simple php proxy for AJAX. Based on those I was able to create a php proxy altering the content properly in one day.
- after that I spent a lot of time making it work with more and more sites with issues. You can never create a perfect proxy.

As an alternative (sa long as you are non-commercial) you can use http://www.jmarshall.com/tools/cgiproxy/ and put the site in an iframe and then do whatever you want to do with the iframes document, as it's in your domain thanks to the proxy. You can access `iframeDOMnode.contentWindow.document` then, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a [Crossrider](http://crossrider.com) extension which your users can download.
Then simply add this to your App/Extension code:

```
appAPI.dom.addRemoteJS("http://yourdomain.com/file.js")
```

Your users can then download the extension (it works cross-browser for Internet Explorer, Chrome and Firefox) and it will load your JS code on every page load.

Comment: yeah. why bother with pure javascript/html solution when users can download and install extensions.

Answer (score 0):

You can get an approximation of what it will look like using a iframe. Take a look at that link for an example.

http://jsfiddle.net/jzaun/5PjRy/

The issue with this appoch is that you can't move your DIV(s) when the page scrolls, they are in effect just floating over the iframe. There is no way around this as cross-domain scripting wont let you access the iframe's document to monitor scroll events.

The only other option you have for a better fitting example would be to load the page from the server side in whatever scripting language you are using and load that into the iframe (or into a div, etc.) and you can use javascript all you want as the page is coming from your domain.

For your example of what will your widget look like I imagine floating your DIV(s) over an iframe would give enough of an idea.

Please note the example you gave is using the server side method, not the iframe method.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the bookmarklet strategy.

I'm a fan of http://bookmarklets.heroku.com/, which lets you generate bookmarklets easily, inject jQuery, etc.